# Parsing large json files

Tags: java, json, swing

I have a problem regarding the conversion of json to csv - especially a memory problem (at least I think it is one). I wrote some functions which should handle this case and it works great - for small json-files. For large json-files the JFrame gets stucked and it happens nothing for minutes (I killed the process with the task manager after ~5min).
The source json-file has about 30.000 lines.

What I'm up to:

- Reading the (large) json-file
- Correct it (some values are not json-typical, i.e. `"actor" : "ObjectId("12345")` etc. should be corrected to `"actor" : "12345"`
- split the large json file into smaller ones.
- process with the small json-files.

What I have so far:

```
public void mongoExportAndSplitFilter() {
    ReadFileAndSave reader = new ReadFileAndSave();
    String jsonFilePath = this.converterView.sourceTextField.getText();
    //String targetFilePath = this.converterView.targetTextField.getText();
    File jsonFile = new File(jsonFilePath);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader.readFileAndCorrectOutput(jsonFile));
    int j = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    reader.readPartOfFileAndSave("src/main/resources", scanner, j, sb);
    //System.out.println("STEP 1: INPUT FILE (" + jsonFilePath + ") HAS BEEN CORRECTED!");
    //System.out.println("STEP 2: INPUT FILE (" + jsonFilePath + ") HAS BEEN SPLITTED WHILE PARSING!");
    this.filterView.setVisible(false);
    this.filterView.dispose();
    this.filterFlag = 1;
}

/**
 * Utility function to correct the MongoExport-JSON-Output.
 *
 * @param file The file which should be corrected.
 * @return Returns the correct JSON-String.
 */
public String readFileAndCorrectOutput(File file) {
    String jsonStringCorrected = "";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String next = scanner.next();

            if (next.contains("ObjectId") || next.contains("ISODate")) {
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile(this.regEx)
                        .matcher(next);

                if (m.find()) {
                    next = next.replaceAll(this.regEx, this.innerString);
                }
            }
            //jsonStringCorrected += next;
            sb.append(next);
        }
        scanner.close();

        jsonStringCorrected = sb.toString();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStringCorrected);
        jsonStringCorrected = jsonObject.toString(2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReadFileAndSave.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return jsonStringCorrected;
}

/*
 * Utility-function to read a json file part by part and save the parts to a separate json file.
 * @param   scanner     The scanner which contains the file and which returns the lines from the file.
 * @param   j               The counter of the file. As the file should change whenever the counter changes.
 * @return  jsonString  The content of the jsonString.
 */
public String readPartOfFileAndSave(String filepath, Scanner scanner, int j, StringBuffer sb) {


    String jsonString = "";
    int i = 0;
    ++j;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String token = scanner.next();

        //jsonString += token;
        sb.append(token);
        if (token.contains("{")) {
            i++;
        }
        if (token.contains("}")) {
            i--;
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            jsonString = sb.toString();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            jsonString = jsonObject.toString(2);
            saveFile(filepath, "actor", j, jsonString);
            jsonString = readPartOfFileAndSave(filepath, scanner, j);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

**EDIT**

Here's a snippet of the file (first 3 lines):

```
{ "verb" : "access", "target" : { "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da0e", "inquiryPhase" : "Orientation", "displayName" : "Orientation", "objectType" : "phase" }, "generator" : { "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09", "displayName" : "LochemC", "objectType" : "ils", "url" : "http://graasp.eu/spaces/5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09" }, "provider" : { "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09", "inquiryPhase" : "ils", "displayName" : "LochemC", "objectType" : "ils", "url" : "http://graasp.eu/spaces/5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09" }, "object" : { "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09", "displayName" : "LochemC", "objectType" : "ils" }, "actor" : { "id" : "Bas Kollöffel (UT)@5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09", "displayName" : "Bas Kollöffel (UT)", "objectType" : "person" }, "published" : "2014-12-08T13:40:45.409Z", "publishedClient" : "2014-12-08T13:40:45.409Z", "publishedServer" : { "$date" : 1418046045490 }, "_id" : { "$oid" : "5485aa5dc372cdbb21daea33" } }
{ "verb" : "access", "target" : { "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da13", "inquiryPhase" : "Conceptualisation", "displayName" : "Conceptualisation", "objectType" : "phase" }, "generator" : { "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09", "displayName" : "LochemC", "objectType" : "ils", "url" : "http://graasp.eu/spaces/5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09" }, "provider" : { "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09", "inquiryPhase" : "ils", "displayName" : "LochemC", "objectType" : "ils", "url" : "http://graasp.eu/spaces/5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09" }, "object" : { "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da13", "inquiryPhase" : "Conceptualisation", "displayName" : "Conceptualisation", "objectType" : "phase" }, "actor" : { "id" : "Bas Kollöffel (UT)@5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09", "displayName" : "Bas Kollöffel (UT)", "objectType" : "person" }, "published" : "2014-12-08T13:40:46.867Z", "publishedClient" : "2014-12-08T13:40:46.867Z", "publishedServer" : { "$date" : 1418046046952 }, "_id" : { "$oid" : "5485aa5ec372cdbb21daea34" } }
{ "verb" : "access", "target" : { "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da1e", "inquiryPhase" : "Investigation", "displayName" : "Investigation", "objectType" : "phase" }, "generator" : { "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09", "displayName" : "LochemC", "objectType" : "ils", "url" : "http://graasp.eu/spaces/5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09" }, "provider" : { "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09", "inquiryPhase" : "ils", "displayName" : "LochemC", "objectType" : "ils", "url" : "http://graasp.eu/spaces/5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09" }, "object" : { "id" : "5485a7050ac61b1339a4da1e", "inquiryPhase" : "Investigation", "displayName" : "Investigation", "objectType" : "phase" }, "actor" : { "id" : "Bas Kollöffel (UT)@5485a7050ac61b1339a4da09", "displayName" : "Bas Kollöffel (UT)", "objectType" : "person" }, "published" : "2014-12-08T13:40:48.582Z", "publishedClient" : "2014-12-08T13:40:48.582Z", "publishedServer" : { "$date" : 1418046048662 }, "_id" : { "$oid" : "5485aa60c372cdbb21daea35" } }
```

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Comment: looks like it would be useful a sax/stax-like json parser for huge json

Comment: First problem: you're using string concatenation in a loop.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Why is this actually a problem?

Comment: @Leo: Sax/Stax doesn't provide the functionality I need later on.

Comment: @X-Fate: See http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/strings.html

Comment: will look throught it and use try to use it instead of the string concatenation. I'm excited what the result will be. Thanks so far.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Now I get a StackOverFlowError. I changed the String concatenation to a StringBuffer.append and after this with toString, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well "it doesn't seem to work" doesn't really explain much about what diagnostics you've performed. It's hard to understand what your method is meant to do, partly because the documentation doesn't match the actual parameters... I would probably try to avoid `Scanner`, and just parse the whole file to a `JSONObject`, rather than all the messing around with text operations - aside from anything else, your current code is quite brittle. If there are multiple braces on a single line, or an escaped brace in a string, it'll break.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: `next()` doesn't take the whole line, but rather the next token. In the json-file I got there is always a space after a token, so that this program wouldn't break, even if it is in just one line. 
However, I edited my programm above. EDIT: Unfortunytely, you cannot put a whole file into the json-Object.

Comment: Ah, yes - had missed that part about only taking a token. That doesn't solve the string issue though. But if the whole file represents a single JSON object, you really should be able to load it in one go...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: What do you mean by "But if the whole file represents a single JSON object [...]"? The whole file isn't just a single JSON-Object. I've got a file with about 30.000 lines. Every line is single json-object. I think this is clearer now.

Comment: @X-Fate: Okay, that definitely wasn't clear before. It would help if you'd give a sample of the file (just a short one, but representative, with multiple objects) in the question. I haven't checked, but I wouldn't be surprised if the JSON API provided some sort of streaming approach for this...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Posted the first 3 from about 30.000 lines in my edit at the top.

Comment: Is there *actually* one JSON object per line? If so, that would make things pretty simple - just read a line at a time and parse each line as JSON... If some objects cover multiple lines (or if there are some lines with multiple objects) then obviously that doesn't work.

Comment: I have to assume that this is NOT the case. Another file covers about 50 lines for a single JSON-Object.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Solved the problem. You are right concerning the memory of the StringBuffer (the single files are smaller than the ones I am using string concatenation). Nonetheless, I'll get a StackOverFlowError at file 3195 (from 3604) and that's not quite that what I wanted (why? well... files can be MUCH larger than the one I have - it is about 5MB only). The real problem was the order of the operations here. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't read the whole file at once. Read it line-by-line, do your corrections, and write to the output as you go.

Also, it does not look like you need to parse and recreate json here. Should be able to do all the processing you need at the raw text level.

And also I don't think you need recursion in your `readPartOfFileAndSave()`, can do everything within the outer loop.

Comment: Actually I read the file token by token. I put it into the `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)` and iterate with `scanner.hasNext()` through the whole file. Or what did you mean?

Comment: You iterate through the whole file, and put the entire contents into a String, and the iterate through the String again, and write output. What I am saying is that you should get rid of that `String`  (that's what eating up all your memory), and just write output as you go, without accumulating more content in memory than you need at a time.

Comment: Yeah, now I get what you mean, but how should I get rid of the String? I need it to process the data in it in some other functions. Pass them directly doesn't make sense in my context, because - for example - I need the whole jsonString (expect, that one jsonString is one valid json-file) to convert it to XML and to process the XML-String in a recursive method to build a new pattern from the nodes, called a xes-file.

Comment: Well, I can only comment on the code you have shown. To perform the task the snippet in your question is doing, you do not need the entire content of the file. Are there other tasks, where reading the entire content of the file into memory is unavoidable? I highly doubt that, but without any knowledge of what you have in mind, this is just an educated based on experience (there is a lot of software, doing all kinds of processing on terabytes of data without loading it all into memory at once, it is unlikely, that your case is a rare exception).

Comment: Sure, I don't need the entire file, but the code I provided shouldn't read the whole file as well. I'm planning to scan the file - token by token - until `i == 0`. If this is the case, this part of the file should be saved. Then the scanner should process until `i == 0` again... this should be the case until there is no new token and the scanner closes. After that I'm planning to convert EACH FILE to ANOTHER temporary file. If this has been done I'm going to MERGE all files together and create one big file again. Hope this is more clear.

Comment: Yeah, it's clear, but it is not what your code is doing. You are reading the entire file into a String, and that is what causes the memory problems you mentioned in your original question.

Comment: I think I know what you mean now. If this should solve the problem, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: You were right. I changed the order: I first split the whole file into smaller ones and THEN do my correction on the smaller files. Thank you!